# 2014 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2014 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://academia.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Answer (score 2):

It seems like we have four winners ! Congratulations to aeismail, eykanal, ff524 and StrongBad (if I ran the correct algorithm for determining the results)

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested, here is a visualization of the raw votes:

[image]

(Thanks to our friends over at [Stats.SE](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1804/41284))